# How to display a List of objects in C# to javascript using Google JS API in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, google-visualization

I have a .Net MVC3 website where I want to draw Pie Charts, but the Google Charts API or maybe JSON doesn't work right in my code and I don't know why.

I tried to refer from this sets of codes: [MVC4 with Google JS API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21729119/how-to-display-a-list-of-objects-in-c-sharp-to-javascript-using-google-js-api-in#new-answer?newreg=291de7e5b6ed4c51b132ccf1d7832ede)

This is my ChartController Code:

```html
 public ActionResult Sales()
        { 
            return Json(CreateList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        public class ItemForChart
        {
            public String Name { get; set; }
            public Int32 Qty { get; set; }
        }

        public IEnumerable<ItemForChart> CreateList()
        {
            List<ItemForChart> list = new List<ItemForChart>();
            ItemForChart itm1 = new ItemForChart() { Name = "A", Qty = 1 };
            ItemForChart itm2 = new ItemForChart() { Name = "B", Qty = 2 };
            ItemForChart itm3 = new ItemForChart() { Name = "C", Qty = 3 };
            ItemForChart itm4 = new ItemForChart() { Name = "D", Qty = 4 };
            list.Add(itm1); list.Add(itm2); list.Add(itm3); list.Add(itm4);
            return list;
        }
```

This is my View Code for the Sale ActionResult

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" >
    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
        $.get('/Chart/Sales', {},
            function (data) {
                var tdata = new google.visualization.DataTable();

                tdata.addColumn('string', 'Name');
                tdata.addColumn('number', 'Qty');

                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    tdata.addRow([data[i].Name, data[i].Qty);
                }

                var options = {
                    title: "Sample Charts"
                };

                var chart1 = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div1'));

                var chart2 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div2'));

                var chart3 = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div3'));

                var chart4 = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div4'));

                chart1.draw(tdata, options);
                chart2.draw(tdata, options);
                chart3.draw(tdata, options);
                chart4.draw(tdata, options);
            });
    }
</script>

<div id="chart_div1" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;">
</div>

<div id="chart_div2" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;">
</div>

<div id="chart_div3" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;">
</div>

<div id="chart_div4" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;">
</div>
```

And when I run the program, it shows this,

[{"Name":"A","Qty":1},{"Name":"B","Qty":2},{"Name":"C","Qty":3},{"Name":"D","Qty":4}]

^it doesn't show any charts but only that.

or if there are other Charts API that I can use that is also easy to learn, I am open for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are browsing to the JSON controller endpoint `localhost/MyApp/Chart/Sales` (which is consumed by the Ajax callback in `google.setOnLoadCallback` to feed data to the chart) - it looks like the JsonRresult is working fine. In order to view the Graph, you'll need to browse to the "Sale ActionResult" route (something like `localhost/MyApp/SomeController/Sale`)

You also have a typo:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        tdata.addRow([data[i].Name, data[i].Qty]);
        //                                     ^ closing array brace
    }
```

[Fixed jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/63gyuoad/1/)

Not directly related, but note that you can use Object initializer syntax on the server C# to simplify matters:

```
 public IEnumerable<ItemForChart> CreateList()
    {
        return new List<ItemForChart>
        {
           new ItemForChart() { Name = "A", Qty = 1 },
           new ItemForChart() { Name = "B", Qty = 2 },
           new ItemForChart() { Name = "C", Qty = 3 },
           new ItemForChart() { Name = "D", Qty = 4 }
       }
    }
```

Comment: actually that part in for-loop, it is a javascript and i just referenced from the website i have given.

Comment: Just to confirm: 
`/SomeController/Sale` => Returns Html + JS to render the charts (which should look like http://jsfiddle.net/63gyuoad/1/)
`/Chart/Sales` => Returns JSON to feed the google charts Ajax Call for data

Comment: Isee. So I can use `/SomeController/Sale` to render my chart? I thought javascript can only read JSON. and I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I tried the code you passed, but there's nothing in my webpage.